# How to save and restore the state of an ExpandableListView in Android?

Tags: android, save, state, expandablelistview, restore

Is it possible to save and restore the state (which items are collapsed and which not) of an ExpandableListView in Android?

If it is possible, how can I do that?

Can I access the ExpandableListView in onPause() / onResume() and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I iterate through the groups and save the state of them all:

```
int numberOfGroups = MyExpandableListViewAdapter.getGroupCount();
boolean[] groupExpandedArray = new boolean[numberOfGroups];
  for (int i=0;i<numberOfGroups;i++)
    groupExpandedArray[i] = MyExpandableListView.isGroupExpanded(i);
```

Then for restore the state:

```
for (int i=0;i<groupExpandedArray.length;i++)
  if (groupExpandedArray[i] == true)
    MyExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
```

I don't understand what you mean by how to access the ListView in onPause() / onResume(), it should be accessible from there if you store the ListView object as a member of the activity class.

Answer (score 4):

Improving Floaf's answer: declare

```
 public static int firstVisiblePosition=0;
```

on Pause

```
int numberOfGroups = MyExpandableListViewAdapter.getGroupCount();
boolean[] groupExpandedArray = new boolean[numberOfGroups];
for (int i=0;i<numberOfGroups;i++){
    groupExpandedArray[i] = MyExpandableListView.isGroupExpanded(i);
}
firstVisiblePosition = MyExpandableListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

onResume

```
for (int i=0;i<groupExpandedArray.length;i++){
  if (groupExpandedArray[i] == true)
      MyExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
}
MyExpandableListView.setSelection(firstVisiblePosition );
```

This will not only restore each group's state but it will also scroll to the childView that was viewed when activity paused.

Answer (score 0):

a simpler way could be, if you're using setOnGroupClickListner and setOnChildClickListener just keep the last selected ChildPosition and GroupPositin integer and later on check it and respond properly,

```
if (childPosition > 0) {
    mExpandableList.expandGroup(groupPositin);
}
mExpandableList.setItemChecked(groupPositin + childPosition , true);
```

you just need to remember set childPosition to 0 in your setOnGroupListener method.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this very same question and found a better answer. I have a fragment and use the **onSaveInstanceState** and **onViewStateRestored** to save and restore the **ExpandableListView**.

*Here I save the state of the list*

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState( @NonNull Bundle outState )
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState( outState );

    ExpandableListView expandable = getView() != null ? getView().findViewById( R.id.expandable ) : null;
    if( expandable != null )
    {
        int groupsCount = expandable.getExpandableListAdapter()
                                    .getGroupCount();
        boolean[] groupExpandedArray = new boolean[groupsCount];
        for( int i = 0; i < groupsCount; i += 1 )
        {
            groupExpandedArray[i] = expandable.isGroupExpanded( i );
        }
        outState.putBooleanArray( "groupExpandedArray", groupExpandedArray );
        outState.putInt( "firstVisiblePosition", expandable.getFirstVisiblePosition() );
    }
}
```

*And here I restore it when it is needed*

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onViewStateRestored( savedInstanceState );
    if( savedInstanceState != null )
    {
        boolean[]          groupExpandedArray   = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray( "groupExpandedArray" );
        int                firstVisiblePosition = savedInstanceState.getInt( "firstVisiblePosition", -1 );
        ExpandableListView expandable           = getView() instanceof ViewGroup ? getView().findViewById( R.id.expandable ) : null;
        if( expandable != null && groupExpandedArray != null )
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < groupExpandedArray.length; i++ )
            {
                if( groupExpandedArray[i] )
                    expandable.expandGroup( i );
            }
            if( firstVisiblePosition >= 0 )
                expandable.setSelection( firstVisiblePosition );
        }
    }
}
```